# Embedded command line tool called via Runtime.exec in a Java sandboxed app on MacOS results in signal 4

Tags: java, macos, sandbox, command-line-tool, jpackage

**Objective**

I want to ship my java app **myapp** to macOS appstore, the app uses a command line tool **mytool** called with:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("mytool", "argument")`

**Tools**

- Mac M1Pro with Ventura 13.1
- OpenJDK 18.0.2 (x64)
- Xcode 14.2

**Problem**

When I try to run it it crashes with the error:

`Cannot run program "/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/app/mytool": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid 64709, signal: 4`

**What I have done so far**

After reading:

- [Embedding a command-line tool in a sandboxed app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/embedding-a-helper-tool-in-a-sandboxed-app)
- [Sign the Application Package (macOS)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jpackage/support-application-features.html#GUID-8D9F0607-91F4-4070-8823-02FCAB12238D)

My understanding is that I have to:

- sign my command line tool **mytool** with entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
<true/>
```

- place that tool inside the .app image and then sign the image

To achieve that I do:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --timestamp --options runtime \
-s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Radoslaw Juszczyk (*********)" \
-i com.rjuszczyk.myapp.mytool \
--entitlements mytool.plist \
-vvvv inputDir/mytool
```

to sign **mytool**, and then I place it in the **inputDir**

Then I copy my **myapp.jar** to the same **inputDir** and execute:

```
jpackage --name MyApp
--input inputDir
--mac-sign --mac-signing-key-user-name "Radoslaw Juszczyk"
--mac-package-signing-prefix com.rjuszczyk.myapp.
--mac-app-store
--type pkg
--mac-entitlements myapp.plist
--main-jar myapp.jar
```

Now it creates **MyApp.pkg** successfully, which passes verification in the *Transporter.app*

When I install it, it installs correctly, and the installed `.app` has this hierarchy:

[image: Contents of the .app]

When the execution hits `Runtime.exec` it crashes with the mentioned above error.

I tried also to specify different launch mechanisms (posix_spawn, fork) in the jpackage tool :

`--java-options "-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=posix_spawn"`

but no luck. My understanding of the problem is that somehow the process started with Runtime.exec does not start in the sandbox, and since **mytool** requires to be inside sandbox it fails to execute (I am not sure if it makes any sense).

**My entitlement files for reference:**

myapp.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.debugger</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- Add additional entitlements here, for example for network or hardware access. -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

mytool.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is the moment when I feel like I run out of options. The only thing which maybe is causing that (but I do not believe it matters) is the fact that I place my **mytool** under `Contents/app` instead of `Contents/MacOS` but I am not sure how make the `jpackage` tool to place it somewhere else.

I hope there is someone who went through the same process and can point out what I am missing. Or point me to some docs describing how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions, especially when building with Xcode if you are also targeting mobile apps, I see you signed the entitlements but *not* the deepsign.

> maybe use `-c --verbose` options to get more debug information to help you out.

---

> Try creating a *new* text file named java.entitlements with the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>


// Now grant these entitlements to the java executable:
codesign -f -s "Mac Developer: John Smith (XYZ)" --entitlements "java.entitlements" "Home/bin/java"
```

Make sure to use your own developer certificate with the correct paths appropriate to your situation.

Because this is a cryptographic operation, complete changes to the Info.plist prior to this step.

Now Configure Tools / for e.g. in Xcode
Make sure that your *application or framework target during build*

- first step will copy
- second step sign this PlugIn bundle when you build. Do this by adding a "New Copy Files Phase" to the target. Rename it to “Copy Java Runtime”), choose PlugIns as the destination, choose the Java.runtime directory, and ensure that code sign on copy is selected.

Sign the Java.runtime bundle
Sometimes code sign on copy will complain that the Java.runtime bundle is not already signed, so you may have to manually deep sign the bundle in order to have your tool or Xcode re-sign it when building your project:

```
codesign --deep -f -s "Mac Developer: John Smith (XYZ)" Java.runtime/
```

---

Ultimately I think it is in the `codesign` [look at this ref. issue on github](https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/1778) to fix it
Someone forced it to code sign to run it ...

```
codesign --force --deep --sign - ./Test-signed.app
```

This is for when a process fails to start on macos similar to yours  https://github.com/libgdx/packr/issues/161

Comment: Unfortunately that was not helpful. In my case the app works just fine until it reaches the line `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mytool ...")`, when it crashes with signal 4. At the end I decided to compile mytool to a dynamic library and call it from JVM via JNI bindings.